# Plotting RDA (vegan) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, vegan

I'm still new to R, trying to learn how to use the library vegan, which I can easily plot in R with the normal plot function. The problem arises when I want to plot the data in ggplot. I know I have to extract the right data from the list I've created, but which and how? The dataset I've been practicing on can be downloaded here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PQGov60aoudVR3dVZBX1VKaHc/view?usp=sharing
The code I've been using to get the data transformed is this:

```
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
data <- read.csv(file = "People.csv", header = T, sep = ",", dec = ".", check.names = F, na.strings=c("NA", "-", "?"))
data2 <- data[,-1]
rownames(data2) <- data[,1]
data2 <- scale(data2, center = T, scale = apply(data2, 2, sd))
data2.pca <- rda(data2)
```

Which gives me a list I can plot using the basic "plot" and "biplot" function, but I am at a loss as to how to plot both PCA and biplot in ggplot. I would also like to color the data points by group, e.g. sex. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `ggbiplot(...)` function in package `ggbiplot`, but it only works with objects of class prcomp, princomp, PCA, or lda.

`plot.rda(...)` just locates each case (person) in PC1 - PC2 space. `biplot.rda(...)` adds vectors to the PC1 and PC2 loadings for each variable in the original dataset. It turns out that `plot.rda(...)` and `biplot.rda(...)` use the data produced by summarizing the rda object, not the rda object itself.

```
smry <- summary(data2.pca)
df1  <- data.frame(smry$sites[,1:2])       # PC1 and PC2
df2  <- data.frame(smry$species[,1:2])     # loadings for PC1 and PC2
rda.plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(df1)),size=4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dotted") +
  coord_fixed()
rda.plot
```

[image]

```
rda.biplot <- rda.plot +
  geom_segment(data=df2, aes(x=0, xend=PC1, y=0, yend=PC2), 
               color="red", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.01,"npc"))) +
  geom_text(data=df2, 
            aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,label=rownames(df2),
                hjust=0.5*(1-sign(PC1)),vjust=0.5*(1-sign(PC2))), 
            color="red", size=4)
rda.biplot
```

[image]

If you compare these results to `plot(data2.pca)` and `biplot(data2.pca)` I think you'll see they are the same. Believe it or not the hardest part, by far, is getting the text to align properly wrt the arrows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jlhoward, although the biplot is different from what I get out of the biplot function - some of the vectors are longer in my biplot? The text is quite annoying yet, I guess there is no easy fix for it?

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that axes do not have equal aspect ratio. I don't use `ggplot2` myself, but it must have a way of setting aspect ratio. It is also better to use `scores()` to access the scaled ordination result -- `summary()` is so convolute.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to have a look at the `ggvegan` package in https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan

Comment: Add `+ coord_fixed()` which sets aspect `ratio = 1` (the default) to get the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Good point. Updated to add `coord_fixed(...)`. I was not aware of `ggvegan`

Answer (score 7):

You can use my **ggvegan** package for this. It is still in-development though usable for some classes of objects including `rda` and `cca` ones.

Assuming the example data and analysis you can simply do:

```
autoplot(data2.pca, arrows = TRUE)
```

to get the sort of biplot you want. This produces

[image]

You can get site labels via

```
autoplot(data2.pca, arrows = TRUE, geom = "text", legend = "none")
```

which also shows how to suppress the legend if required (`legend.position` takes values suitable for the same theme element in **ggplot2**).

[image]

You don't have a huge amount of control other the look of things with `autoplot()` methods (yet!), but you can use `fortify()` to get the data the way **ggplot2** requires it and then use ideas from the other answers or study the code for `ggvegan:::autoplot.rda` for the specifics.

You need to install **ggvegan** from github as the package is not yet on CRAN:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

which will get you version 0.0-6 (or later) which includes some minor tweaks to produce neater plots than previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

According to @jlhoward you can use `ggbiplot` from the package with the same name. Then the only thing you need to do is to cast your `rda` result to `prcomp` result that is known by `ggbiplot`. Here is a function to do that:

```
#' Cast vegan::rda Result to base::prcomp
#'
#' Function casts a result object of unconstrained
#' \code{\link[vegan]{rda}} to a \code{\link{prcomp}} result object.
#'
#' @param x An unconstrained \code{\link[vegan]{rda}} result object.
#'
#' @importFrom vegan scores
#' @export
`as.prcomp.rda` <-
    function(x)
{
    if (!is.null(x$CCA) || !is.null(x$pCCA))
        stop("works only with unconstrained rda")
    structure(
        list(sdev = sqrt(x$CA$eig),
             rotation = x$CA$v,
             center = attr(x$CA$Xbar, "scaled:center"),
             scale = if(!is.null(scl <- attr(x$CA$Xbar, "scaled:scale")))
                         scl
                     else
                         FALSE,
             x = scores(x, display = "sites", scaling = 1,
             choices = seq_len(x$CA$rank),
             const = sqrt(x$tot.chi * (nrow(x$CA$u)-1)))),
        class = "prcomp")
}
```