# Customizing a vegan pca plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, vegan

I'm trying to make a custom plot of some vegan rda results in ggplot2. I'm essentially modifying directions as seen in [Plotting RDA (vegan) in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194193/plotting-rda-vegan-in-ggplot), so that I am using shape and color labels to convey some information about the sample points.

I set up a pca analysis with vegan as follows

```
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73",  "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7", "#F0E442")
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
dune.pca <- rda(dune)
uscores <- data.frame(dune.pca$CA$u)
uscores1 <- inner_join(rownames_to_column(dune.env), rownames_to_column(data.frame(uscores)), type = "right", by = "rowname")
vscores <- data.frame(dune.pca$CA$v)
```

I can make a simple biplot

```
 biplot(dune.pca)
```

[image: test biplot]

Now, lets say I want to know more about the management conditions to which these different samples were subject. I'll color and shape code them and plot with ggplot.

```
p1 <- ggplot(uscores1, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, col = Management,
                         shape = Management)) + 
geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(values=cbPalette) +
scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:25)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
p1
```

[image: test points]

Next, I'd really like to add some biplot arrows that show us the axes corresponding to species abundance. I can use ggplot to plot just those arrows as follows:

```
p2 <- ggplot() +  geom_text(data = vscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = rownames(vscores)), col = 'red') +
geom_segment(data = vscores, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")),
            alpha = 0.75, color = 'darkred')
p2
```

[image: test arrows]

What I'd really like to do though, is get those arrows and points on the same plot. Currently this is the code that I am trying to use:

```
p3 <- p1 + geom_text(data = vscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = rownames(vscores)), col = 'red') +
geom_segment(data = vscores, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")),
            alpha = 0.75, color = 'darkred')
p3
```

To my annoyance, this yields only a blank plot (empty window, no error messages). Clearly I am missing something or scaling something incorrectly. Any suggestions about how I can best superimpose the last two plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
library(cowplot) #not needed I just had it attached while answering the question hence the theme.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(uscores1) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, col = Management,
                     shape = Management)) +
      scale_color_manual(values=cbPalette) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) +
      scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:25)) +
      geom_text(data = vscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = rownames(vscores)), col = 'red') +
      geom_segment(data = vscores, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")),
                   alpha = 0.75, color = 'darkred')+
      theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

The `p1` plot was passing `col` and `shape` variable `Management` to `geom_text/geom_segment` since they were not defined there but there is no `Management` column in `data = vscores`. At least I think so based on the error:

```
`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Management' not found`
```

Comment: Your observation let me to realize that this problem is super analogous to my earlier problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159950/using-different-data-in-ggplots-geom-rug-than-i-use-in-the-rest-of-the-plot/46160097#46160097.

Comment: Here's an even more minimal re-write of my code that gets it working: `p3 <- p1 + 
geom_text(data = vscores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = rownames(vscores)), col = 'red', inherit.aes = F)+
geom_segment(data = vscores, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")),
            alpha = 0.75, color = 'darkred', inherit.aes = F)`

Comment: You **must** add `+  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)`: ordination plots must use equal aspect ratio.

Comment: In addition to the use of `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)`, there is another caveat: your example uses unscaled raw scores, but in plots you want to take into account the eigenvalues and stretch axes with high eigenvalues, and shrink those with low eigenvalues. You can do all this by hand, but you *must* do it. Our plotting and scores functions do this automatically, as does **ggvegan** package. In general, you should *never* access scores directly as `dune.pca$CA$v`, but you should use `scores` function that also scales the scores like needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Now, my code for calculating scores reads as: `allscores <- scores(dune.pca);
uscores <- data.frame(allscores$sites);
uscores$ptvis <- rownames(uscores);
uscores1 <- inner_join(rownames_to_column(dune.env), rownames_to_column(data.frame(uscores)), type = "right", by = "rowname");
vscores <- data.frame(allscores$species);` and I have aded the `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)` line at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Check **ggvegan** package from [github](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan). It is still in 0.0 versions, and not actively developed at the moment, but if you say

```
library(ggvegan)
autoplot(dune.pca) # your result object
```

You get this graph which you can customize in the usual **ggplot2** way with various aesthetics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dr. Oksanen. GGvegan does sound promising. My concern with such an approach is that, as far as I can tell, it is not trivial to modify the site point colors and shapes. For instance, in your example above, the sites are all red squares, but I would like the shapes to depend on management type. I can use the fortify() function to export the data and then feed it into ggplot, but then I run into the same problem I described above. Somebody correct me if I am missing something here though. I would rather do this with ggvegan if I could as it would save me several lines of code.

Comment: The `autoplot()` methods are intended (by original design of the `autoplot` concept I think) to give you a plot. Internally they use the `fortify()` methods provided also by ggvegan to prepare a tidy data structure suitable for plotting with ggplot2 where you can have full control. Look at the code for one of the the autoplot methods in the package to get a sense of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at ggordiplots on GitHub (https://github.com/jfq3/ggordiplots). It includes the function gg_env__fit which fits environmental vectors to an ordination plot. All of the functions inthe package silently return data frames that you may use to modify the plots anyway you wish. The package includes a vignette on modifying the plots. You can read the vignettes without having to install the package by going to john-quensen.com and looking at the GitHub page.