# R vegan - what are 'species' and 'sites'

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to perform RDA in R, using the package vegan and, well, it's getting a bit confusing. This is quite tricky to explain, but hopefully I make some sense...

The vegan package is developed for ecological data. Because of that it seems to use  'sites' and 'species' as specific named terms/factors in the model?

This is confusing as some datasets (e.g. Iris) have columns named 'species' for example.

I do not have sites, nor species. I have plots IDs, each plot has been applied fertiliser (characterised by 5 independent variables) and for each plot plant nutrition has been analysed (6 dependent variables).

I don't quite understand exactly what "species" and "site" are referring to within Vegan. For example, at this link:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/259028_dbe846c67e144065b4c2bcd012fb130d.html

[image]

Sorry for the ignorance, this is one package I've struggled with. Previously, I've done plenty of PCAs using prcomp and GGFortify, but it appears there isn't an equivalent route for RDA.

Comment: You could try my {ggvegan} package, which is only on GitHub https://gavinsimpson.github.io/ggvegan/ : it can fortify the scores you need for plotting plus is has some canned `autoplot` methods for vegan's ordination functions

Answer (score 2):

Sites are the samples (the things which are measured e.g the plots in your case) and species are properties or features of the samples. A biplot shows both how features are different and how samples are different. For `display='sites'`, site data is used directly for the axes and the species are just being drawn relatively to them. So it's just to set your perspective.

Comment: Okay, so in this example a "site" would simply be one individual (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231583/4919664).

For me, it considers my dependent variables (nutrition) as what it calls "species". "Site" would be each individual sample from each plot.

thanks.

Comment: Yes. Site is one individual, one patient or one location.

Comment: Thanks again - the wording get's a bit confusing, though I appreciate that the package was developed for a very specific purpose and is now being used more broadly for wider RDA needs.

Comment: @AndrewCooke Yeah, but even then we could have done this more intuitively (and internally we don't use these names in the internal representation of these models anyway, so it's just the interface to extract the scores). So, we could make this easier by allowing say `"samples"` or `"observations"` as an alias for `"sites"` and `"variables"` (or some such) as an alias for `"species"` (we already have `"wa"` for "`sites"` which is itself confusing as the scores are weighted averages in an PCA/RDA...)